quisiera poder ocupar un codigo de Astro en React
el siguiente div:
<div class={`overflow-hidden bg-slate-500 shadow-lg rounded-lg p-6 border border-slate-100 hover:border-gray-700 flex-none justify-start relative transform w-full transition duration-75 ease-in-out col-span-1 h-auto ${
          colSpan || "md:col-span-2"
        } ${rowSpan || ""}`}
>

es parte de un componente de tarjeta, el cual me permite definirle la ubicación en el main desde el componente, esto funciona super bien en astro, ya que le puedo definir que colspan y rowspan sean iguales a astro.props, pero me gustaría poder ocupar este código en react y no he podido realizarlo.
<Card colSpan="md:col-span-1" rowSpan="md:row-span-1">

Cualquier ayudar con esto, estaria bien agradecido!.

y por qué no al revés? https://docs.astro.build/es/guides/integrations-guide/react/
